# How much does network security audit and patch work?

Tags: pci-dss, security-theater

how much is reasonable if i'm looking to hire someone FULL TIME to handle security auditing and patching for my network?  I need my network to be PCI Compliance and what not as well.  MY office have about 15 workstations that consists of Sales Dept, Accounting Dept, and Shipping Department.

i bought a SonicWall NSA security router, so the person will have to manage and monitor that along with ASP, PHP, JAVA intranet system.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is too vague - it's unanswerable. How long is a piece of string? We don't know what the salary is like in your country, or state/city. We don't know what other requirements you're expecting. We don't know about other benefits you provide.

Comment: For 15 desktops it would be OK to outsource it to consultant, so he setups this once and reviews once every year.

Comment: This question also has little long-term use.  The job markets change regularly, and an estimate today would quickly be outdated within a couple years, if not just a few months.

Comment: This is a business decision, not a security decision - still I would suggest you read the [relevant PCI compliance info](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3.pdf) and weight the costs of a person's salary and the amount of insurance they can bring you towards PCI compliance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is worth it to hire a 'security guy' for a 15 workstation company.  I think YOU are the security guy for your company (since you bought the router).  But,  if being attacked is something you are worried about and you think security is important then hire one.

This is a business question, not a security question.